# Strange button behavior in safari/opera

Tags: javascript, html

The `<button>` tag appears to have strange behavior in Safari and Opera (but not Firefox). If the button contains text, then we have the following cases:

- if you click your mouse then release without moving the mouse, **onClick occurs**.
- push down on mouse button on non-text area of button, drag mouse to other non-text area of button, release, **onClick occurs**.
- push down on mouse button on text area of button, drag mouse to other text area of button, release, **onClick occurs**.

However, bizarrely:

- push down on mouse button on text area of button, drag mouse to non-text area of button, release, **onClick does not occur**.
- push down on mouse button on non-text area of button, drag mouse to text area of button, release, **onClick does not occur**.

This is strange behavior. Most of the time it is not noticed, but if you press a button quickly your mouse can move while you are clicking. This means it looks like you clicked the button, but it doesn't activate.

Is this a known problem? I presume it is because the text isn't part of the button itself, just a child element? Is there a good way around it? `<input type=button>` doesn't have this behavior, presumably because the text isn't a separate html element from the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` is new and still highly experimental. It should be used only in conjunction with HTML5. And yes, it is buggy, not only in Safari and Opera, even Chrome has issues.

My advice is to use `<input type="button" />` instead, until after all modern browsers support  most of the new standard.

Best is to wait until HTML5 is official, but... well... that's going to be a long wait.